# Error : unknown file system while trying to install Debian on my Mac mini

Tags: startup, efi

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8 on a Mac mini 2.1. The hard disk is 80 GB and the first half is occupied by the Mac OS X and on the second half I'm trying to install Debian. I tried to follow a lot of different tutorials and two Linux distros:

1. debian-mac-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso
2. debian-mac-8.6.0-i386-netinst.iso

Also, I've installed rEFIt and/or rEFInd, but nothing. The error I get is always the same:

```
status: got partition of type "unknown" found,will not touch this disk. Error: not found returned from gptsync.efi.
```

I get this error when I do "start partitioning tool" from rEFIt. And also another error:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
```

So, after 3 days of hard work, I don't know what to do.

NB :

[image: screen1]

Comment: Were you able to boot to a live image?

Comment: Are you using an optical drive, USB flash drive or other method to install?

Comment: yes,from the cd-dvd reader,but not from the usb stick.

Comment: I tried using the cd-dvd optical driver most of the time.

Comment: My computer is a mid 2007 iMac. Your computer is a mid 2007 mac mini. I am burning debian-mac-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso to a RW DVD. I will see if I can recreate your problem. I have Yosemite (0S X 10.10), El Capitan (OS X 10.11) and 64 bit Windows 10 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reach the point in the installation process where I needed to create partitions to install Debian. This partitioning was part of the Debian installer. I did not encounter the same problems you have reported.

I am not sure why you are using rEFIt and/or rEFInd. I did not need to.

Some of the steps I took:

- I burned the file "debian-mac-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso" to a RW DVD
  using the Disk Utility application. The OS X was Yosemite. I assume
  Snow Leopard would work the same.
- I did not need rEFIt or rEFInd to start the installation. I just
  restarted the Mac and held down the option key to invoke the Startup
  Manager. Next, I inserted the DVD and waited for the DVD icon labeled
  "EFI boot" to appear. Finally I select this icon to boot from.
- I choose the "Graphical install" option when prompted.
- My connection to the internet is hardwired, so I did not have to
  configure wireless settings.
- The installer did not have the software for Broadcom wireless
  hardware in my Mac. I instructed the installer to bypass this
  problem.

Perhaps you could modify your question to include the output from the following Terminal application commands. These commands will not change your Mac. The commands just give me a better understanding of how your drive is partitioned.

```
diskutil list
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
```

Comment: I added the information you requested as a picture on the main post.